# Android and JSR-105 package XML digital signature

Tags: android, xml, certificate, package

I would like to know if its possible to include package JSR-105 in Android project?

http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr105/index.html

If yes, can you please explain how?